# Installing WordPress on Mac OS X Server

Tags: osx-server, webserver, websites, wordpress

I have a Mac Mini with Yosemite OS X Server, i would like to install WordPress and  Magento on the server and use it for local development before I push my completed sites to the live server with the hosting provider.

1. How to Install WordPress / Magento on Mac Mini Server?
2. Is Installing WordPress on Mac OS X server different from installing on Mac?
3. How to access such Sites on local Network and from outside the local Network (example let customer preview the website).
4. I don't have a fixed IP address. I understand there are some other free services to solve such issues.

As of now, I can Access my wiki from outside the network with `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/wiki`.

The IP address may change from time to time on my server and I have to make a note of it.

The Apple Help documents are a bit vague to me as I am new to server and especially Apple server and its Server App.

Also I am able to access the website though not the index page but a image placed in my site/default directory named `1.jpg` by going to `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/1.jpg`.

If some one could help me shed more knowledge on working with WordPress installation will be of great help.

Comment: Please split your question in two different ones: one with q1+q2 about WP/Magento and ask a new one with q3+q4 about accessing LAN web servers with changing IPs from the outside world. The latter might already be asked and answered here.

Comment: Thanks Klanomath. will check out. but installing wordpress and magento I can handle as I have done it many times. only thing i wanted to know is if the preparations has to be done differently for Server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) It's a self contained installation of Apache, MySQL, PHP and that you can hack around in to your hearts content and not mess up your system's configuration.

I've even hosted websites off of it. Highly recommended!

Comment: Yes Steve, thanks ! for the info i have done it in my iMac too. but on a server i don't know if that helps in a big way from using the inbuilt web server options. i wanted to use the local install directories and not the ones installed by bitnami any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: it's very easy.

First, go to http://www.mysql.com/downloads/ and get the database (it's not included on OS X anymore, Apple switched to postgres).

Next, go to http://dyn.com/remote-access/ (or similar) and get a working domain with a dynamic address. Wordpress does NOT like IP addresses, and the webserver will only deliver the server default site if you access it by IP.

If you only need local access you can just use the built-in DNS server or make an entry in the /etc/hosts file. But the sites you make will not be viewable from any other computer, including others on your local network.

Side note: servers, in general, do not like having their IP address changed. I set up my server with a fixed local (192.168. ) address, the dynamic address is on the router where the server neither knows nor cares that it's different.

Comment: Thanks ! let me try it today !

Yes I too have a Fixed Local IP for the server, but my routers address keeps changing. I suppose that is why u want me to use the service from dyn.com

Comment: Correct. That's what I've used for years, it works very well. My server is happy as it's ip address never changes, others are happy because they can access my server.

Comment: The Instructions given By Paul was greatly helpful. I installed mysql using the script suggested in the below Site. But unfortunately the script couldn't install Sequel Pro, since the software is on google servers and I was downloading from China (Thanks to the great firewall). later managed to download and install it separately and mysql worked well. Installed PHP using http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com and since i didn't want to go for paid dynamic dns installed duckdns but unfortunately this site is blocked in china. yet to complete the installation.